# Java class vs SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite

В моем приложении для хранения данных используются Java классы с массивами данных. Так вот, у меня вопрос, есть ли смысл переносить данные из Java классов в базу данных SQLite? Будет ли какое-либо преимущество в скорости либо в чем-то еще перед обычным Java классом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ наконец-то, то что мне нужно. Может кому пригодится, оставляю здесь, потому что на русском stackoverflow не нашел.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760579/android-local-database-sqlite-vs-internal-classes-through-a-singleton

Вкратце суть в том, что внутренний класс дает очень маленькое преимущество в скорости, поэтому если перевод приложения на базу данных трудоемкий, можно не переводить.

Answer (score 4):

В первом случае, Ваши данные доступны **только во время выполнения программы**. После завершения работы программы Ваши данные, при таком подходе, пропадают.

Во втором случае, Вы можете записать данные в базу данных, завершить работу программы, а при следующем запуске прочитать эти данные из базы данных. Этот вариант подходит для **долговременного хранения данных**.

Comment: а почему нельзя при следующем запуске приложения прочитать из того же Java класса? В классе инициализированные массивы с постоянными значениями, куда они могут пропасть?

Comment: А каким образом Вы собираетесь «прочитать из того же Java класса»? И что такое «массивы с постоянными значениями»?

Comment: просто, НазваниеКласса.Название массива с данными. И я не собираюсь, у меня уже так всё сделано, я думаю, будет ли плюс от того, что я буду использовать ДБ.

Comment: а массив с постоянными значениями это public static final

Comment: А, Вы хотите узнать разницу между хранением данных *непосредственно в коде программы* и в базе данных?

Comment: да, именно так))

Comment: Данный вопрос очень общий и ответ на него зависит от конкретной ситуации. Если у Вас там что-то типа `int a = 5` – то пожалуйста. Но в моем понимании термина *хранение данных* он никакого отношения к Вашему первому случаю не имеет.

Comment: У меня что-то вроде массива объектов, каждый объект имеет имя, id ресурса изображения. Этого объекта.